# How to replace new nodes from document1 to document 2 in XML using Marlogic?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I am having 2 documents-

```
1. doc1-
<root>
   <id1>1</id1>
   <id2>243</id2>
   <id3>3343</id3>
   <id4>4454</id4>
   <id5>546</id5>
</root>

2. doc2-
<root>
   <id1>1</id1>
   <id2>abc</id2>
   <id3></id3>
   <id4></id4>
   <id6>35545</id6>
   <id7>Delhi</id7>
</root>
```

If (id1 is equal) I want an output something like this-

```
<root>
   <id1>1</id1>
   <id2>243</id2>
   <id3>3343</id3>
   <id4>4454</id4>
   <id5>546</id5>
   <id6>35545</id6>
   <id7>Delhi</id7>
</root>
```

Basically i am updating my doc2 by taking the content from doc1.

Code:-

```
declare function local:replace-nodes($doc_2 as node(), $doc_1 as node()){
let $doc := 
    for $each-node in $doc_1//*/*[text()]
    return xdmp:node-replace($doc_2//*/*[local-name(.)=fn:local-
 name($each-node)], $each-node)
 return "Nodes Replaced"
};
```

from the above code i am getting the below output-

```
<root>
  <id1>1</id1>
  <id2>243</id2>
  <id3>3343</id3>
  <id4>4454</id4>
  <id6>35545</id6>
  <id7>Delhi</id7>
</root>
```

i.e; nodes are getting replaced but it is not inserting the extra nodes [id5 in this case] from doc1. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that id5 does not exist in doc2 and you are using [`xdmp:node-replace`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace). You cannot replace a node that doesn't exist. You need to expand your logic to handle this case using something like [`xdmp:node-insert-child`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-insert-child) when it occurs.

Comment: Thanks Rob. But i am confused on how can i use xdmp:node-replace and xdmp:node-insert-child simultaneously in one function ? or xdmp:node-insert-child will do the job for xdmp:node-replace as wel ?

Comment: @Shalini You can use if statements in xquery. if node exists then replace, else insert. If you're really struggling please get in touch with MarkLogic Consulting: https://www.marklogic.com/product/consulting-services/

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do it the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
let $a := $doc1/root/*[data(.)]
let $b := $doc2/root/*[data(.)]
let $c := element x {$a, $b}/*
let $d := <r>
          {
            for $i in $c
            order by $i/name(), $i/text()
            return $i
          }
          </r>
return    <s>
          {
            for $g in $d/*
            let $gg :=  $g[. ne following-sibling::*[1]] 
            return $gg
          }
          </s>
```